# How to lock down Grails spring-security-ui controllers?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am creating my first Grails app and am using the spring-security-core and spring-security-ui. I have locked down controllers that I have created in my application but there is a gaping hole left in the fact that any unauthenticated user can hit the spring-security-ui controllers.  What is the proper way to limit access to those controllers to specific roles?

I am considering running s2ui-override on each of those controllers and then implementing secured annotations at the class level.  Is this a sound approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I generally use annotations for application controllers and static rules in `Config.groovy` for the controllers provided by plugins like spring-security and spring-security-ui:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/aclClass/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/aclSid/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/aclObjectIdentity/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/aclEntry/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/persistentLogin/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/requestmap/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/securityInfo/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/registrationCode/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/role/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/user/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
    '/console/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],

    '/register/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is precisely what I was looking!

Comment: @ataylor I didn't know you could mix static rules with controller annoations! Is this the same with database requestmaps?